# Defining a list index outside of a for loop results in list out of index error

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = [3, 7, 8, 5]

B = [6, 2, 1, 4]

k = [3, 7, 8, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4]
```

I want to compare the numbers and add them to a third list like this:

```
sortiert = []
x = 0
i = 0
j = 0
while x < len(k): 
    if A[i] > B[j]:
        sortiert.append(B[j])
        j += 1
    elif B[j] > A[i]:
        sortiert.append(A[i])
        i += 1
    x += 1
```

However I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For this line:

```
if A[i] > B[j]:
```

Why do I get this error when I defined `i` and `j` as 0?

How can the list index be out of range if the list is not empty?

Comment: where do you define k?

Comment: @Jay Mody, I forgot it, added it to the OP. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you debug this by printing out the array indices `i` and `j` as you go along?

Comment: You are iterating 8 times (`len(k)`), but what happens if, for example, each time you increment `j` because `A[i] > B[j]`? You'll get a `j` outside the range of  indexes of `B`. Same for `i` and `A`.

Comment: In your if statements what should happen if A[i] == B[j]?  Is this supposed to be a merge sort of A&B?

Comment: @jarmod I tried this and I had the suspicion that ````len(k)```` might be the problem, but I cant put my finger on it, hence the question.

Comment: What are actually trying to do? What's your desired outcome here?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am trying to do a merge sort

Comment: It seems you are looping trough the list len(k) times and len(k) < i, A[i] is out of  Range:  looping to many times. A reach index 3 only. Double check it, not 100% sure.

Comment: @gython if you doing the merge part of merge sort shouldn't A and B be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you exhaust one list -- when you have added all four of its elements to `sortiert` -- then the corresponding index increases to 4.  On the next loop iteration, you try to compare `A[1] > B[4]`, causing the fault.

You did not handle the case when the only remaining elements were all in one list.

1. You can see how to merge two lists by consulting any reference on how to implement a Python merge-sort.
2. In the future, learn to insert strategic `print` commands to trace the operation of your program.  This is a very basic, but very effective debugging tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [3, 7, 8, 5]
B = [6, 2, 1, 4]

sortiert = []
x = 0
i = 0
j = 0

while x < len(A): # <- not sure what your reference to k is?
    if A[i] > B[j]:
        sortiert.append(B[j])
        j += 1
    elif B[j] > A[i]:
        sortiert.append(A[i])
        i += 1
    x += 1
    print(sortiert)
```

This runs on python3.7, but doesn't seem to operate greater than operator correctly in the append function. I appended while loop to len(A) as it'll throw and out of range error if you try to keep looping though a list once it is out of range.

Comment: I see you have now added your reference to k - it will error because the lists A & B will be out of range.